# Cardinality of equivalence relations in $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, cardinals, equivalence-relations

I came across this long proof on this site:

[Cardinality of relations set](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/18046/cardinality-of-relations-set)

But I would like to know whether my direction can work.

Say we want to find the cardinality of all equivalence relations in $\mathbb{N}$. Since it is a subset of all relations in $\mathbb{N}$, I conclude it has a cardinality smaller or equal to $\aleph$. Now, define an injective function from $P(\mathbb{N})$ to the set of equivalence relations by matching each subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with the identity relation (which is an equivalence relation in $\mathbb{N}$.

Therefore the cardinality of all equivalence relations in $\mathbb{N}$ is greater or equal to $\aleph$ and using CSB we get the desired result.

Seems legit?

Comment: Already wanted to upvote your previous question but was marked as duplicate. Was not too sure why to be honest.

Comment: "subgroup of $\mathbb{N}$"?

Comment: Oops. In Hebrew the word for "group" is used to describe a "set". Quite confusing. Will edit.

Comment: I don't think you're using $\aleph$ correctly (you seem to be using it for the cardinality of the powerset of $\mathbb{N}$). You may prefer to write: "I conclude it has cardinality smaller than or equal to $2^{|\mathbb{N}|^2},$ and hence cardinality smaller than or equal to $2^{\aleph_0}$."

Comment: Isn't $2^{\aleph_0}$ equal to $\aleph$?

Comment: @Whyka: No, $2^{\aleph_0}$ is equal to $c$, the cardinality of $\mathbb R$. I have never seen $\aleph$ without a subscript (in a mathematical context).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach is sound.  I think you can choose a better injection from $P(\mathbb{N})$ into equivalence relations.  Let us say $0 \in \Bbb N$ and we will inject $P(\Bbb N \setminus\{0\})$ into the equivalence relations on $\Bbb N$.  I would suggest you take a subset of $\Bbb N \setminus\{0\}$ to the equivalence relation that groups all members of the subset and $0$ into an equivalence class and leaves all the rest of $\Bbb N$ under the identity.

If we don't do the trick with $0$, all singleton subsets will be mapped to the identity relation and you don't have an injection.